# macOS Mojave: Text file that I downloaded from my personal Google Drive triggers App Security Check?

Tags: terminal, applications, mojave, security, google-apps

I have a large (a few GB) text file that I downloaded from my personal Google Drive.

It's a text file, although it wasn't labeled with a ".txt".

When I try to open it in a text editor, I get the security warning for an unidentified App.

```
“mytextfile.dump” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer. 

Your security preferences allow installation of only apps from the App Store and identified developers.

Chrome downloaded this file yesterday at 11:46 PM from takeout.google.com.
```

Okay....so I `cmd-i` to get file Info, and under the preview tab, it shows the text. It looks good.

I change the file extension so it's now `mytextfile.txt`. I still get the security issue?

Is this a bug? Is there some low-level flag that makes it look like an app? Or is there a hidden app attached to it? What's going on?

Yes, tried to `cd` into it from the Terminal, and it says it isn't a directory.
Yes, I tried `ls -l` on it, and no, it wasn't executable.

I also tried `mdls mytextfile.txt` and the first entry is:

```
_kMDItemDisplayNameWithExtensions  = "mytextfile.app"
```

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: If you launch Terminal and run `file mytextfile.dump`, what is the output? If you have enough free disk space and the file is indeed a text file, have you tried duplicating the file (for example, with this command in Terminal: `dd if=mytextfile.dump of=mytextfile.txt bs=1m`) and see if you can open `mytextfile.txt`?

Comment: Could it be that the file is marked with the "quarantine" flag?  Try an `ls -l@ mytextfile.dump` to see if there is a `com.apple.quarantine` entry. If so, you can remove it with `/usr/bin/xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine mytextfile.dump`.